# Sequelize upsert or create without PK

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, upsert

I'm unable to perform any kind of upsert or create within Sequelize (v: 6.9.0, PostGres dialect).

Using out-of-the-box `id` as PK, with a unique constraint on the `name` field. I've disabled timestamps because I don't need them, and `upsert` was complaining about them. I've tried manually defining the PK id, and allowing Sequelize to magically create it. Here's the current definition:

```
const schema = {
    name: {
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }
};

class Pet extends Model { }
Pet.define = () => Pet.init(schema, { sequelize }, { timestamps: false });

Pet.buildCreate = (params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let options = {
        defaults: params
        , where: {
            name: params.name
        }
        , returning: true
    }
    Pet.upsert(options)
        .then((instance) => {
            resolve(instance);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            // message:'Cannot read property 'createdAt' of undefined'
            console.log(`ERROR: ${e.message || e}`);
            reject(e);
        });
});
module.exports = Pet;
```

Upsert code:

```
// handled in separate async method, including here for clarity
sequelize.sync();

// later in code, after db sync
Pet.buildCreate({ name: 'Fido' });
```

In debugging, the `options` appear correct:

```
{
    defaults: {
        name: 'Fido'
    },
    returning:true,
    where: {
        name: 'Fido'
    }
}
```

I've also tried `findOrCreate` and `findCreateFind`, they all return errors with variations of `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

I've tried including `id: null` with the `params`, exact same results.

The only way I've succeeded is by providing PK in the params, but that is clearly not scalable.

How can I upsert a Model instance without providing a PK id in params?

Comment: I've encountered the same error. I suspect there's a bug in the library

Comment: Is it possible that your `id` column is not an identity column?

E.g. assuming your `id` column is an integer.

`const schema = { id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true  }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pet extends Model { }
//...you might have the id for the pet from other sources..call it petId
const aPet = Pet.findCreateFind({where: {id: petId}});
aPet.attribute1 = 'xyz';
aPet.attribute2 = 42;
aPet.save();
```